# Windows SNMP hrSystemDate - how to get the timezone?

Tags: windows, snmp

I'm trying to debug some monitoring code that uses SNMP, and have come across an issue.

If I run `snmpwalk -v 1 -c  $COMMUNITY $SERVER hrSystemDate.0` on a Windows 2003/2008/2008R2 machine, I get an output like

```
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0 = STRING: 2012-2-16,16:30:21.1
```

But the same check on a Linux machine (debian) yields.

```
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemDate.0 = STRING: 2012-2-16,16:31:23.0,+11:0
```

The Windows version lacks a timezone.

Is this a known/documented limitation on Microsoft's part? And/or is there another way to get the timezone out by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out his one.

Instead of using SNMP walks, I can use a internal script (part of nagios/nsclient) to run:

```
w32tm /monitor /computer:mytimeserver.com
```

That gives an offset value that takes into consideration a change in timezones (offset is within reasonable bounds when changing from +10 to +11, but breaks if the hour changes +1)

Answer (score 0):

It is not in SNMP in any way that I can see.  However, if you have SMB access and have Samba installed on your management station, you can do:

```
net time zone -S $SERVER
```